# PHP: How can I write IF statement that detects when XML value is NULL?

Tags: php, xml

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get my if statement to recognize when an XML value is NULL.  It seems as though no matter what I try, the <li>'s are still printed.

```
// PHP sample
$a = $xml->sentence1;
$b = $xml->sentence2;

if ( isset($a) || !empty($b) ){
    echo '<ul>';
    if ($a !== NULL){
        echo '<li>' . $a . '</li>';
    }
    if ($b !== ''){
        echo '<li>' . $b . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

// XML sample
<sentence1></sentence1>
```

As you can see, I tried all sorts of stuff — NULL, isset(), empty() — but the <li>'s always render.

Comment: consider casting to string: `$a = (string) $xml->sentence1;`

Answer (score 1):

This worked

```
if ( $a == true || $b == true ){
    echo '<ul>';
    if ($a == true){
        echo '<li>' . $a . '</li>';
    }
    if ($b == true){
        echo '<li>' . $b . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

This makes me think that boolean functions (like "isset()") were overkill in this case, but I wonder why they did not work nonetheless.